# how to call controller action from anchor tag

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, dom

In my page, I am dynamically creating anchor tags using jquery, when clicking on the link I want to redirect user to other controller action with one parameter.

So I implemented code like this

My Jquery DOM is :

```
courses += '<a style="cursor:pointer" href="/Coursemaster/LoadCourseMaster/'+result[i].coursecode.toString() + '">' + result[i].coursename + '</a>'.
```

My Controller action is:

```
public ActionResult LoadCourseMaster(string code)
{
   -- some code
}
```

when I debug at controlleraction, string code is coming as null. So I am not able to get code from anchor..

How can I achieve this. any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance..

Comment: `@Html.ActionLink(result[i].coursename, "LoadCourseMaster", "Coursemaster", new { code = result[i].coursecode })`

Comment: the name result does not exist in the current context. i m getting this error

Comment: What is `result`? Is it a javascript variable? In which case, no it wont. Update your question to make it clear what your doing.

Comment: and also i think this solution will display code in url as query string like localhost/coursemaster/loadcousemaster/code=xxxx.. right.. i dont want like this instead i want to show as localhost/coursemaster/loadcoursemaster/xxx..

Comment: yes it is the java script variable, i.e result of jquery ajax success call  success: function (result) {

Comment: Of course it wont- it will generate `.../coursemaster/loadcousemaster/xxx` but if `result` is a javascript variable then it wont work anyway

Comment: can u please suggest me the way to resolve this ...

Comment: You should start by showing your code (the ajax call). And have you inspected the html your generating - is the value of the `href` attributes being generated correctly?

Comment: yes, html is generated correctly likt this ../coursemaster/loadcoursemaster/xxx and debug also fired in controller action.

Comment: And have you defined a route for this - `routes.MapRoute(name: "??", url: "{controller}/{action}/{code}", ...`?

Comment: No didn't  declared route .

Comment: You need to declare a specific route, or you need to change it to `href="/Coursemaster/LoadCourseMaster?code=' + result[i].coursecode.toString() ....` Without the route (and assuming your using the default route with `...{id}`) your `code` value is being passed as to the `id` parameter (alternatively change the method to `LoadCourseMaster(string id)`

Comment: thanks a lot stephen.. u gem.. resolved issue, by changing action parameter from code to id it worked perfectly..  thanks again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved .. by stephen muecke ..

HTML Jquery should be ..

```
courses += '<a style="cursor:pointer"href="/Coursemaster/LoadCourseMaster/'+result[i].coursecode.toString() + '">' + result[i].coursename + '</a>'
```

controller action parameter should be as route parameter.

```
public actionresult loadcoursemaster(string id)
```